sympy: how to factor expressions inside parentheses only
I want to simplify the following expression using sympy:
-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*u*(u**2 + v**2) - 5*beta*u*(u**4 + 2*u**2*v**2 + v**4) - 8*gamma*omega*v

So it ends up like
-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*u*r**2 - 5*beta*u*r**4 - 8*gamma*omega*v

with r**2=u**2+v**2
It is not working though, but when I use
factor(u**4 + 2*u**2*v**2 + v**4).subs(u**2+v**2, r**2)

The output I get is r**4 as expected. Unfortunately, I don't get this simplification when I try this with the first expression. I wonder if there is a way to tell sympy to factor only the expressions inside the innermost parentheses.
Here is the full code
from sympy import symbols

u, v, r = symbols('u v r')
# parameters
alpha = symbols('alpha', positive=True)
beta = symbols('beta', positive=True)
F_p = symbols('F_p', positive=True)
gamma = symbols('gamma', positive=True)
omega = symbols('omega', positive=True)
Omega = symbols('Omega', positive=True)
f=-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*u**3 + 6*alpha*u*v*v - 5*beta*u**5 - 10*beta*u**3*v**2 - 5*beta*u*v**4 - 8*gamma*omega*v
print(f)
f = collect(f, [alpha, beta])
print(simplify(f))
# Substitute u^2 + v^2 = r^2
subs_dict = {u**2 + v**2: r**2}

# Simplify the expression
simplified_expr = simplify(f.subs(subs_dict))
print(simplified_expr)
print(factor(u**4 + 2*u**2*v**2 + v**4).subs(u**2+v**2, r**2))


What does it actually simplify to? My suspicion is that you will also need to provide it with the explicit subst {u**4 + 2*u**2*v**2 + v**4: r**4}. Algebra systems can sometimes be very literal about what they will substitute. If all else fails try it in Maxima.

Sometimes the easiest thing to do is to re-arrange the expression you are trying to replace:
>>> f.subs(v**2, r**2 - u**2).expand()
-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*r**2*u - 5*beta*r**4*u - 8*gamma*omega*v

For an older version of SymPy, that doesn't replace the v**2 in the way you want, you might have to fall back to using v, instead and then cleaning up residual v-expressions.
>>> s=sqrt(var('r',positive=True)**2-u**2)
>>> f.subs(v,s).expand().subs(s,v)
-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*r**2*u - 5*beta*r**4*u - 8*gamma*omega*v


Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, this approach failed with my version of sympy (1.5.1 that had I installed via pip (no newer version seems to be available through pip)). I am using Ubuntu. What version of sympy are you using?

__version__ = 1.11.1 what output did you get?

See updated answer for a guess at how to work around the issue you might have had with the older version.

version = 1.5.1.

Great, that worked now! But definitely, I will upgrade my python and sympy to up-to-date versions

One way to achieve your goal is to select the addition of 3 terms, modify it to your liking, and substitute the result back into the expression. Something like this:
from sympy import symbols, collect, simplify, Add

u, v, r = symbols('u v r')
# parameters
alpha = symbols('alpha', positive=True)
beta = symbols('beta', positive=True)
F_p = symbols('F_p', positive=True)
gamma = symbols('gamma', positive=True)
omega = symbols('omega', positive=True)
Omega = symbols('Omega', positive=True)
f=-8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*u**3 + 6*alpha*u*v*v - 5*beta*u**5 - 10*beta*u**3*v**2 - 5*beta*u*v**4 - 8*gamma*omega*v
f = collect(f, [alpha, beta])
f = simplify(f)
# Substitute u^2 + v^2 = r^2
subs_dict = {u**2 + v**2: r**2}

item = [t for t in f.find(Add) if len(t.args) == 3][0]
new_item = item.factor()
print(item, "\n", new_item)
# u**4 + 2*u**2*v**2 + v**4 
# (u**2 + v**2)**2

print(f.subs(item, new_item).subs(subs_dict))
# -8*F_p + 8*Omega*u + 6*alpha*r**2*u - 5*beta*r**4*u - 8*gamma*omega*v


That worked partially. I got -8F_p + 8Omegau + alpha(6u**3 + 6uv**2) - 5betar**4u - 8gammaomega*v. I think it has to do with my old version of sympy (1.5.1).  How to use your approach to an unspecified number of inner items (sub expressions inside parentheses)?
